# Loading nib on OS X from NSViewController

Tags: macos, nswindow, nib

I'm trying to load a `NSWindow` from an `NSViewController` on OS X and i'm doing the following:

```
private lazy var discoverable: DiscoverableWindow = {
     return DiscoverableWindow.instanceFromNib()
} ()
```

The static method `instanceFromNib()` is defined as below:

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> DiscoverableWindow {
    var instance = DiscoverableWindow()
    var objects: NSArray?
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DiscoverableWindow", owner: instance, topLevelObjects: &objects)
    return instance
}
```

I'm using the window to show from my `NSViewController`:

```
    NSApp.beginSheet(self.discoverable, modalForWindow: NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow!, modalDelegate: nil, didEndSelector: nil, contextInfo: nil)
```

However, when I load it I see the following:

[image]

Is there something i'm doing incorrectly? Why is the `NSWindow` blank? I read the following on this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

[Cocoa - loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects: from loaded bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126985/cocoa-loadnibnamedownertoplevelobjects-from-loaded-bundle)

[Cocoa: NSApp beginSheet sets the application delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463435/cocoa-nsapp-beginsheet-sets-the-application-delegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make a window controller to handle the `DiscoverableWindow`?

Create a subclass of `NSWindowController`, make sure "Also create xib file for user interface" is selected. Configure your window in the `DiscoverableWindowController` xib, uncheck "Visible At Launch" on the properties inspector for the window.

[image]

Then, in your `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction func showSheet(sender: NSButton) {
    let discoverableWC = DiscoverableWindowController(windowNibName: "DiscoverableWindowController")
    view.window?.beginSheet(discoverableWC.window!, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Generally, each window in your app should be managed by its own window controller, let the window controller handle the nib loading and instantiation for you.

[Download the sample project here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Discoverable%20Window.zip).

Comment: This works if you want to show DiscoverableWindow as a sheet. But, DiscoverableWindowController doesn't receive UI events like mouse clicks. I have this project https://github.com/Nordin-010/OSXModalView, which doesn't react on button click on the modal view. Maybe you know how to fix that?